# Importing custom debug header files to lldb

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, lldb

I am debugging a piece of code using lldb and I want to insert my own crafted headers so I could see objects in memory in the correct *logic* layout.

lldb does this on his own when it has the debug symbols, but I want to do that for structs which do not have debug symbols out of the box.

I've come across this link: https://gist.github.com/zcutlip/11ab0e0b4333636bbd2d46541714f617
but unfortunately it does not seem to be working anymore.

I know this has something to do with `module.modulemap` files, I just can't seems to be able to create them in a way that lldb understands that he needs to look at them.

#### For example

I have this struct:

```c
struct test_st {
    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;
}
```

I want to be able to access a random buffer and see it's summery as if it was the struct:

```
(lldb) x 0x0000000283e4db40
0x283e4db40: 59 8e 4b dc 01 9b 7b 01 00 48 e0 27 01 00 00 00  Y.K...{..H.'....
0x283e4db50: c0 46 e0 27 01 00 00 00 67 88 b0 bd f3 c5 0e a7  .F.'....g.......
```

What I want to have is:

```
(lldb) p *(struct test_st*)0x0000000283e4db40
(struct test_st) $2 = {
  (uint64_t) a = 0x017b9b01dc4b8e59;
  (uint64_t) b = 0x0000000127e04800;
}
```

But what I get is:

```
(lldb) p *(struct test_st*)0x0000000283e4db40
error: <user expression 4>:1:1: incomplete type 'struct test_st' where a complete type is required
*(struct test_st*)0x0000000283e4db40
^
<user expression 4>:1:10: forward declaration of 'test_st'
*(struct test_st*)0x0000000283e4db40
         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

lldb can import llvm "Modules" as described here:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html

There isn't a C-language way to ask the compiler to import a module, but there is in ObjC, so you can use that.  The module has to be in the header paths for the expression parser, either in the standard include paths for the compiler, or in directories added with the `target.clang-module-search-paths` setting.  Then you do:

```
(lldb) expr -l objc -- @import ModuleName
```

A more limited way to do this is to put some stand-alone definitions in the "expression prefix" file which gets `#included` into expressions.  You specify this file using the `target.expr-prefix` setting.  Since this gets included for every expression evaluation you don't want to put complex multi-header includes here.  But it's sometimes useful to put a few common structure definitions in here.

Finally, if you can't get either of these to work, for simple structures you can just define your own versions in the debugger.  For instance:

(lldb) expr struct $test_st { uint64_t a; uint64_t b; }

defines the structure.  The `$` in front of the struct tells lldb you want this to be a persistent definition in the expression parser.

(lldb) expr *($test_st*) 0x12345

will then work.